# firebase.auth is not a function. (In 'firebase.auth()', 'firebase.auth' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
(function () {
    var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    var uiConfig = {
        callbacks: {
            signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult, redirectUrl) {
                // User successfully signed in.
                // Return type determines whether we continue the redirect automatically
                // or whether we leave that to developer to handle.
                return true;
            },
            uiShown: function () {
                // The widget is rendered.
                // Hide the loader.
                document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
            }
        },
        // Will use popup for IDP Providers sign-in flow instead of the default, redirect.
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        signInSuccessUrl: 'main.html',
        signInOptions: [
            // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
            firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        // Terms of service url.
        tosUrl: 'terms.html',
        // Privacy policy url.
        privacyPolicyUrl: 'privacy.html'
    };

    // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
})()
```

I am stuck here. I don't know where I went wrong. I used Firebase in my login page. I added all the codes provided from the official docs but when I run it it's not showing and giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly initialise firebase library

```
const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: 'Your Api key ',
      authDomain: 'your ap id .firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://auth-78930.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'xxxxx',
      storageBucket: 'xxxxxxx',
      messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxx',
      appId: '1:674783690996:web:7dde6f4aa97cd79a7c9ea1',
      measurementId: 'G-CWBS2XMR3F',
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    try {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);

      // firebase.analytics();
    }
```

You can get the configuration options from firebaseconsole

Comment: Actually I added all the code but getting the error auth not defined

Comment: It Should get execute before the above function getting called , can u add the configuration to this function ?

Comment: OR make sure that above mentioned function will get executed only post to  the configuration code execution

Comment: ys sir actually i added the the code to a seperate firebase.js and added to my index.html and then to a seperate js file i added the login info just as told in the official docs. But everytime I try to use firebase in web it is showing auth not defined.

Comment: You are getting this error because , Firebase library initialisation not yet happened

Comment: what to do sir?

Comment: For testing can you move the initialisation part to beginning of the function that you asked as question

Comment: Add confiuration before this line var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

Comment: sir when i added the whole initialization code. It is showing FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app). When i added firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); only its showing ReferenceError: Can't find variable: firebaseConfig

Comment: Add a try catch

Comment: try {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);

      // firebase.analytics();
    }

Comment: do i need to install anything in my pc

Comment: node js ...actually its my 1st time using this. I just coded in vscode .